# How to extract particular field space separately in shell script using sed command

Tags: bash, shell, sed

*Input File :* **Test.txt**

```
-rw-r--r--  1 dev dev  93K Sep 18 05:37 Server-23091805496-2-AC.log
-rw-r--r--  1 dev dev  40K Sep 18 05:44 ServerM-23090331-5709-log.log
-rw-r--r--  1 dev dev 484K Sep 18 05:46 Server-280334-12570-log.log
-rw-r--r--  1 dev dev 235K Sep 18 05:47 Server-233405500-1-AC.log
```

**Output in 1st File :**

```
Sep 18 05:37 Server-23091805496-2-AC.log
Sep 18 05:44 ServerM-23090331-5709-log.log
Sep 18 05:46 Server-280334-12570-log.log
Sep 18 05:47 Server-233405500-1-AC.log
```

**Output in 2nd File :**

```
Server-23091805496-2-AC.log
ServerM-23090331-5709-log.log
Server-280334-12570-log.log
Server-233405500-1-AC.log
```

**Tried Below :**
**1.** *sed 's/ /\n/g' Test.txt*
**2.** *ls -ltr | grep "Sep 18 08:" |sed -n '1p'|cut -d ' ' -f2*

Comment: Since the entries on the right-hand column are filenames, substituting the space would destroy filenames with a space in them. Your `cut` command should however not select field 2, but all fields starting with field 9 (filename), i.e. `cut -d ' ' -f 9-`.

Comment: Please read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: [There](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) you will find information on how to format your question with Markdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One answer could be:

```
sed <input.txt -e 's/.*K //g;w file1.txt' -e 's/.* //g;' >file2.txt
```

Or better:

```
sed <input.txt -e '
   s/^\([^[:space:]]\+[[:space:]]\+\)\{5\}//;
   w file1.txt' -e '
   s/\([^[:space:]]\+[[:space:]]\+\)\{3\}//;' >file2.txt
```

Where

- `sed` is run only once, without any fork to other tool,
- 1st removing *everything until `K`*  in first proposal,

  removing **non-spaces followed by spaces**, repeated 5 times, in second proposal
- then `w` write to file `file1.txt`
- At this point, first script part end with second quote, then a second part of script start with `-e` sed argument (see [stevesliva's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77124850/how-to-extract-particular-field-space-separately-in-shell-script-using-sed-comma/77124913?noredirect=1#comment135967959_77124913) for explanation about this.).
- Removing everything until last space in first proposal,

  removing **non-spaces followed by spaces**, repeated 3 times, in second proposal
- Then send `sed`'s *standard output* to `file2.txt`

If `ls -l` show date in some language like *french* printing day as 1st field, justified to 2 characters (`%2d`), to keep the *day* field *justified* in `file1.txt`, you could add a little 2 chars requirement in 1st `sed` command:

```
ls -l /some/path | sed -e '
   s/^\([^[:space:]]\+[[:space:]]\+\)\{5\}\( [0-9] \|[0-9]\{2\} \|[A-Z]\)/\2/;
   w file1.txt' -e '
   s/^ \?\([^[:space:]]\+[[:space:]]\+\)\{3\}//;' >file2.txt
```

So 1st field is either a *space followed by a digit* or *two digits*. (The add a *potential* space at begin of last replacement command).

**Note:** In this, I've used *redirection* for input (`<input.txt`), but this is not a need. Please read my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77124850/how-to-extract-particular-field-space-separately-in-shell-script-using-sed-comma/77124913?noredirect=1#comment135963181_77124913) in answer to [Mark Setchell's coment.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77124850/how-to-extract-particular-field-space-separately-in-shell-script-using-sed-comma/77124913?noredirect=1#comment135963103_77124913)

Comment: Thank You!! Can you provide explanation of each field between s and g ?

Comment: Why do you use input redirection, please? I mean `sed <input.txt ...` rather than `sed -e ... -e ... input.txt`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Because of my way of reflexion... I'd made some tests using `ls -l | ...`, so I was thinking *filter*. Using redirection is a *natural* way of working with a *filter*. Anyways you're right there is no **need** to use redirection.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you for your comment. I've cited them in my answer!

Comment: I'd call the separate arguments to `-e` *commands* not *scripts*.  GNU sed allows you to use multiple `-e` to imply a line break (needed for `w` command), but like any sed the algorithm runs a single script of one or more commands for each load of the pattern buffer from the input stream.  You can have labels for branch commands in the several `-e` ... they're specifying one script.

Comment: @stevesliva thanks for comment,. I've edited my answer, adding a link to them!

Answer (score 1):

This job is for `awk` not for `sed`. Try this:

```
$ echo '-rw-r--r--  1 dev dev  93K Sep 18 05:37 Server-23091805496-2-AC.log' | awk '{print $1}'
-rw-r--r--
$ echo '-rw-r--r--  1 dev dev  93K Sep 18 05:37 Server-23091805496-2-AC.log' | awk '{print $5}'
93K
$ echo '-rw-r--r--  1 dev dev  93K Sep 18 05:37 Server-23091805496-2-AC.log' | awk '{print $9}'
Server-23091805496-2-AC.log
```

Comment: But requirement is sed :)

Comment: If the filename is i. e. `foo  bar  .baz`,  you would print only `foo`. You have to print everything from field 9 to the end.

Comment: You said:  *This job is for awk not for sed.* ... See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77124913/1765658)!

Comment: Great answer but it's more convenient to do this with `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -Ene 'h;s/\s*\S*//6g;G;s/(.*)\n\1\s*//;w file1' 
      -e 'h;s/\s*\S*//4g;G;s/(.*)\n\1\s*//;w file2' file
```

Make a mask of the strings you want to remove, remove them and write the result to  a file.

In this case, perform the operation twice for a second file.

Answer (score 0):

Using `rev` and `awk`

```
$ rev Test.txt|awk 'NF=4'|rev
Sep 18 05:37 Server-23091805496-2-AC.log
Sep 18 05:44 ServerM-23090331-5709-log.log
Sep 18 05:46 Server-280334-12570-log.log
Sep 18 05:47 Server-233405500-1-AC.log

$ rev Test.txt|awk 'NF=1'|rev
Server-23091805496-2-AC.log
ServerM-23090331-5709-log.log
Server-280334-12570-log.log
Server-233405500-1-AC.log
```